# How to fix my bidirectional one to many relationship in Spring Boot

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, jpa

I am trying to make an one to many relationship between two tables, one of the two is the Aggregate root table (Vessel). But when I am creating a new entity the many to one table doesnt map its foreign key to the one to many table's primary key. What I am doing wrong?

## Vessel Table (One to many)

```java
@Entity
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "vessel_info")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "vessel_id_seq",sequenceName = "vessel_id_seq", initialValue = 1,allocationSize = 1)
public class Vessel {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator ="vessel_id_seq" )
    @Column(name = "vessel_code")
    private Long vesselCode;

    private String name;
    private Long companyId;
    private Long  imo;
    private String type;
    @Column(name = "fleet_id")
    private Long fleetId;
    private String yard;
    private Integer hn;
    private Date delivered;
    private Double age;


    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "vessel",cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
            targetEntity = BoilerInfo.class, orphanRemoval = true,fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<BoilerInfo> boilerInfo ;
```

## BoilerInfo Table (Many to one)

```java
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "boiler_info")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "boiler_id_seq",sequenceName = "boiler_id_seq", initialValue = 1,allocationSize = 1)
public class BoilerInfo {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator ="boiler_id_seq" )
    private Long id;


    private String maker;
    private String type;
    private String tubeType;
    private String exhGasByPass;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, optional = false,targetEntity = Vessel.class)
    @JoinColumn(name="vessel_code",nullable = false)
    private Vessel vessel;


}
```

## CREATE VESSEL

```java
private final VesselRepository vesselRepository ;
@Override
public Vessel create(Vessel entity) {
    log.info("Creating {}.", entity);
    Vessel vessel = vesselRepository.save(entity);
    return vessel;
    }
```

## JSON POST

```
{   
    
    "fleetId":"1",
    "name":"BOILERTEST",
    "type":"temp",
    "companyId":"1",
    "boilerInfo":[{
        "maker": "temp",
        "type":"temp"
    }]
}
```

[The logs from the SQL query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EcGPn.png)

Answer (score 0):

Set both side of relation:

```
vesel.getBoilerinfos().add(boilerInfo);
boilerInfo.setVesel(vesel);
```

Comment: Shouldn't this relation be created by its own? through the ORM ?

Comment: No, you have to set it explicitly

Comment: It seams it works for creation but now when I delete the vessel the boiler isnt.

Comment: Create new question with new problem description. If my answer helped to solve problem in question, mark it as correct